# How to find the Closed Form Expression of the function $f$ that outputs the number of ones in the binary expression of a given natural number?

Tags: number-theory, functions, closed-form, binary

I am interested in finding the closed form expression of the number of ones in the binary expression of the given natural number.

I have no idea whether it is possible to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One can easily write expression as sum of digits. I believe there is no closed-form solution without sum sign or using some special function.

Comment: More information on the function f can be found at https://oeis.org/A000120.

Comment: $$                  s_2(n) = n - \sum_{i=1}^\infty   \left\lfloor  \frac{n}{2^i} \right\rfloor       $$